# My android application is getting stopped while running in device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am a beginner in android development. As per my testing, I found that the app is not running because of following line in MainActivity.java.

```
     tasklist=db.getAllTasks();
```

here is the main Activity code

```
<pre><code>
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DialogEndListener{

    private ToDoAdapter taskAdapter;
    private List<ToDoModel> tasklist;
    private Databases db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();

        RecyclerView taskRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.taskRecler);
        taskRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
       taskAdapter=new ToDoAdapter(db,this);
        taskRecyclerView.setAdapter(taskAdapter);
        tasklist =new ArrayList<>();
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        db=new Databases(this);
        db.openDatabse();
       ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper=new ItemTouchHelper(new ListTouchHandler(taskAdapter));
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(taskRecyclerView);


        tasklist=db.getAllTasks();
        Collections.reverse(tasklist);
        taskAdapter.setTasks(tasklist);

       fab.setOnClickListener(v -> NewTaskAddition.newInstance().show(getSupportFragmentManager(),NewTaskAddition.TAG));
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    @Override
   public void handleDialogClose(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
        tasklist=db.getAllTasks();
        Collections.reverse(tasklist);
        taskAdapter.setTasks(tasklist);
        taskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
</pre></code>
```

I think the fault must be in database code.

```
<pre><code>
    public class Databases extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int VESRSION =1;
    private static final String NAME="appDatabase";
    private static final String TODO_TABLE="todoTable";
    private static final String ID="todoId";
    private static final String TASK="taskDesc";
    private static final String STATUS="taskStatus";
    private static final String CREATE_TODO_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+ TODO_TABLE+" ( "+ID+
                                                                           " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                                                                           + TASK +"TEXT, "+STATUS+
                                                                           " INTEGER)";
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public Databases(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, NAME, null, VESRSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TODO_TABLE);   //embedded sql
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    //drop existing table
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TODO_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public void openDatabse(){
        db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void insertTasks (ToDoModel tasks){
        ContentValues value= new ContentValues();
        value.put(TASK, tasks.getEachtask());
        value.put(STATUS,0);
        db.insert(TODO_TABLE,null, value);
    }

public List<ToDoModel> getAllTasks(){
        List<ToDoModel> taskList =new ArrayList<>();

    db.beginTransaction();
    try (Cursor sqlcursor = db.query(String.valueOf(Boolean.parseBoolean(TODO_TABLE)), null, null,
                                                                            null, null, null,
                                                                                   null, null)) {
        if (sqlcursor != null) {
            if (sqlcursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    ToDoModel thisTask = new ToDoModel();
                    thisTask.setId(sqlcursor.getInt(sqlcursor.getColumnIndex(ID)));
                    thisTask.setEachtask(sqlcursor.getString(sqlcursor.getColumnIndex(TASK)));
                    thisTask.setStatus(sqlcursor.getInt(sqlcursor.getColumnIndex(STATUS)));
                    taskList.add(thisTask);
                } while (sqlcursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
return taskList;
}

public void updateStatus(int id,int status){
        ContentValues value=new ContentValues();
        value.put(STATUS,status);
        db.update(TODO_TABLE,value,ID+"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
}

public void updateTask(int id,String tasks){
    ContentValues value=new ContentValues();
    value.put(TASK,tasks);
    db.update(TODO_TABLE,value,ID+"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
}
public void deleteTask(int id){
    db.delete(TODO_TABLE,ID+"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});

}
}

</pre></code>
```

Can someone help me identifying the error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's because _getAllTasks()_ may have not data in database. Debug code and check size of _getAllTasks()_

Comment: Please add your error logs(Stack trace).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a table called false or true as you are using `String.valueOf(Boolean.parseBoolean(TODO_TABLE))` for the table name (neither table exists).

If you inspected the log then you would have seen something along the lines of :-

```
2021-10-09 10:49:14.468 25593-25593/a.a.so69499435manager E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: false
2021-10-09 10:49:14.468 25593-25593/a.a.so69499435manager D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-10-09 10:49:14.471 25593-25593/a.a.so69499435manager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: a.a.so69499435manager, PID: 25593
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{a.a.so69499435manager/a.a.so69499435manager.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: false (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM false
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: false (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM false
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:514)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1408)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1126)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1332)
        at a.a.so69499435manager.Databases.getAllTasks(Databases.java:58)
```

- i.e. the table false could not be found because you query ends up being :-

  `SELECT * FROM false`
- You may wish to have a read of https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/#systemLog (and other sections in the linked page)

I believe you should just be using :-

```
Cursor sqlcursor = db.query(TODO_TABLE, null, null,
            null, null, null,
            null, null)
```

However :-

- Running a single SQL in a transaction has no benefit.
- A Cursor will NEVER be null when returned from any SQliteDatabase method that returns a Cursor, Checking for null is useless.
- Try/catch on SQLite more often than not introduces confusion. If an exception occurs then more than likely it MUST be fixed. e.g. you appear to have missed the ***table false not found error***
- `while(thecursor.moveToNext) { .... }` is more concise then a moveToFirst while moveToNext loop.
- you should ALWAYS close a cursor when done with it *(not doing so may eventually result in a crash because too many Cursors are open)*.

As such perhaps consider the following :-

```
public List<ToDoModel> getAllTasks(){
    List<ToDoModel> taskList =new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor sqlcursor = db.query(TODO_TABLE, null, null,
            null,null,null,null,null);
    while(sqlcursor.moveToNext()) {
        ToDoModel thisTask = new ToDoModel();
        thisTask.setId(sqlcursor.getInt(sqlcursor.getColumnIndex(ID)));
        thisTask.setEachtask(sqlcursor.getString(sqlcursor.getColumnIndex(TASK)));
        thisTask.setStatus(sqlcursor.getInt(sqlcursor.getColumnIndex(STATUS)));
        taskList.add(thisTask);
    }
    sqlcursor.close();
    return taskList;
}
```

**More**

You may also wish to address the fact that the table will not have a column named **taskDesc** but will instead have a column named **taskDescTEXT** as you have omitted a space between the column name and it's type.

Instead of

```
private static final String CREATE_TODO_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+ TODO_TABLE+" ( "+ID+
        " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + TASK +"TEXT, "+STATUS+
        " INTEGER)";
```

- results in
- [image]

You probably want :-

```
private static final String CREATE_TODO_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+ TODO_TABLE+" ( "+ID+
        " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + TASK +" TEXT, "+STATUS+ //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED a space before TEXT
        " INTEGER)";
```

- results in
- [image]

If you make this change (add the space). The easy way to do this is to uninstall the App and then rerun it after changing the code. However, you will lose any existing data.

- If you need to retain data and apply the change and don't know how then I'd suggest asking another question.